# The size of an array created from np.random.normal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, gaussian

I am using the numpy's `random.normal` routine to create a Gaussian with a given mean and standard deviation.

```
array_a = an array of len(100)

gaussian = np.random.normal(loc=array_a,scale=0.1,size=len(2*array_a))
```

So I expect the `gaussian` to have a `mean=array_a` and `stddev=0.1` and the size of the `gaussian` array to be 2 times `array_a`. 
**However the above returns me an array with the same size as that of `array_a` !**

How do I get the `len(gaussian)` to be **2 times** `len(array_a)` with the given `mean` and `standard deviation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to multiplicate `len(array_a) * 2` instead of `len(array_a * 2)` and `loc=array_a.mean()`
Try:

```
import numpy as np

array_a = np.arange(100)
gaussian = np.random.normal(loc=array_a.mean(), scale=0.1, size=2 * len(array_a))
```

Now `gaussian.size` is `200` and `gaussian.mean()` is equal to `array_a.mean()`.

Comment: I would like the mean to be each value in `array_a`, and not the mean of `array_a`.

Comment: so you want 100 gaussians as output?

Comment: NO!! Each value in `gaussian` will have a different mean. i.e. the first `gaussian` value will have the `mean = first object` of `array_a` and so on.

Comment: i don't understand. can you explain with a quantitative example what do you expect?

Comment: Actually I now understand! What I wanted was to create a single gaussian array, but with the `mean` being each value of `array_a`. But this is not possible if I want a final array of a size greater than `array_a`. So your method will work, provided I give a single `mean` value.